# Where to store XML files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I am writing a Ruby on Rails site which loads some data from an "local" XML file which I have. Where is a logical place in the rails directory structure to store this file?

Comment: Is it some kind of configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main question here is for what reason you have that XML files: configuration info or data storage. If first - then best place will be *congif* folder, otherwise - anywhere you like except *public* folder, you could even create *xml* folder inside *app* one.

Comment: It is for data storage. I have created a folder app/data to store it in which I think works well.